# Exclude an xml node

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am stuck in something that probably for you might think is simple!

In an xml file I have these nodes

```
<Types>
  <Pas type="1" single="Man" plural="Men" />
  <Pas type="2" single="Woman" plural="Women" description="this is a test" />
  <Pas type="3" single="Child" plural="Children" description="this is another test" />
</Types>
```

Then in an xslt file a have javascript and I am filling a variable

```
Details = {<xsl:for-each select="/Types/Pas">"<xsl:value-of select="@type"/>": {single:"<xsl:value-of select="@single"/>",plural:"<xsl:value-of select="@plural"/>"}
```

So far so good. At some point in the xslt i have this

```
(<xsl:value-of select="$Details/@desc" />)*
```

because i want to show the description in () with a * at the end.

And i am getting this:

```
Men()*
Women(this is a test)*
Children(this is another test)*
```

The problem is that i dont want the ()* in Men.

Is there any way to exclude it?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an xsl:if statement like this:

```
<xsl:if test="@description">
     (<xsl:value-of select="$Details/@desc" />)* 
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked like this    <xsl:if test="$Details/@description">
        (<xsl:value-of select="$Details/@description" />)*
       </xsl:if>

Answer (score 1):

You just have to put this particular piece of code :

```
(<xsl:value-of select="$Details/@description" />)*
```

Into a conditional statement e.g.

```
<xsl:if test='current()/@description and string-length(current()/@description) > 0'>
  (<xsl:value-of select="$Details/@description" />)*
</xsl:if>
```

Note that this also takes care of empty attributes.

Comment: Note that this test expression is equivalent to the much shorter `test="string(@description)"`.